# prevent system from getting locked

Tags: windows, windows-security

How can we prevent system from getting locked, There are group of systems in our office which needs to run 24/7 with getting locked, these are lab machines.

I do have admin rights but group policies apply preventing from changing registry and windows updates options

looking for a best and easy way for preventing system getting locked

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/329758/how-can-i-prevent-a-policy-enforced-screen-lock-in-windows-7

Comment: Talk to the admins who set the group policies. Have them create a separate policy for these machines. If that would violate policy then you need to talk to whomever has sufficient authority to grant you an exception.

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the best solution but you can download software to fake mouse inputs to stop the computers falling asleep. I personaly use this one : https://mousejiggler.codeplex.com/